# Whats the meaning of this parameter?

Tags: currency

I was looking the currency exchange board, and I saw the value of "exotic" for the parameter Group, what is the meaning of this value?
[image]

I dont know if this is a local figure or is used in currency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currencies and currency pairs are sometimes classified as Major, Minor, or Exotic, depending on how heavily traded they are (Major most heavily traded, Exotic least).